# Rename FTP folder name using c# (Or move a ftp folder to the same directory with different name)

Tags: c#, ftp

I am using third party dll named SecureFtpCnnection, but that doesn't have any method to rename the folder or copy one folder to another folder, could you please help me out in this.

dll referene is here https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/api/html/Methods_T_EnterpriseDT_Net_Ftp_SecureFTPConnection.htm

Thanks

Comment: Ahem, choosing another library could help a lot.

Comment: i am bound to use that dll. i have tried lots of options from internet like FtpWebRequest class but doesn't much help :(

Comment: At least try to tell us what FTP product are you using. I can't find any reference to this dll

Comment: sure, dll reference link is here https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/api/html/Methods_T_EnterpriseDT_Net_Ftp_SecureFTPConnection.htm

Answer (score 0):

The baseclass of SecureFTPConnection, ExFTPConnection seems to have a Method "RenameFile", commented with "rename a file or directory". I couldn't check if that's a relative or absolute path you have to give it, but I guess its relative. So change dir to the parent dir and

```
conn.RenameFile("oldDir", "newDir");
```

https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/api/html/M_EnterpriseDT_Net_Ftp_ExFTPConnection_RenameFile.htm

Comment: ohh great thanks :) . but if same name folder is already exists then it will overwrite that folder?

Comment: I can't answer that from the top of my head, sorry. But I could check tomorrow. Or you could do a little test yourself. The safest way would be to check, if the target directory exists by https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/api/html/M_EnterpriseDT_Net_Ftp_ExFTPConnection_DirectoryExists.htm and if it returns false then rename, otherwise choose a new name...

Comment: Hi, so I had a closer look at your library, and it seems if you rename and the target folder already exists, it tries to complete the operation. I guess it  depends on the ftp server implementation what it does. I tried with our cerberus instance and it put the source folder "oldDir" INSIDE of the target folder "newDir" (so then there was a path ./newDir/oldDir) if newDir already existed. So just stick with checking for existence of your new directory name first, before renaming to prevent unwanted behavior.

Comment: glad I could help! could you mark my answer as a valid answer then? thanks!